# MVC4 Entity Framework -- How do I display One-to-Many Relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have a class with with one-to-many relationship and trying to display the virtual object in the view. I am fairly new to MVC and EF so this maybe something simple.

I am trying to display a drop down list for PODObject on "Request/Create" action view.

Here are the models

```
 public class PODObject
    {
        public int PODObjectID { set; get; }
        public string name { set; get; }
        public string CustomAttribute1 { set; get; }
        public string CustomAttribute2 { set; get; }
        public string CustomAttribute3 { set; get; }
        public string CustomAttribute4 { set; get; }
        public string CustomAttribute5 { set; get; }
        public virtual ICollection<BookingObject> BookingObjectspublic { set; get; }    
    }

public class RequestsQueueObject
{
    // Request Attributes
    public int RequestsQueueObjectID { set; get; }
    public string CustomAttribute1 { set; get; }
    public string CustomAttribute2 { set; get; }
    public string CustomAttribute3 { set; get; }
    public string CustomAttribute4 { set; get; }
    public string CustomAttribute5 { set; get; }

    public int PODObjectID { set; get; }

    public virtual PODObject PODObject { set; get; }
}
```

Here is the controller Create action

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="RequestsQueueObjectID,POCPODAccess,CustomAttribute1,CustomAttribute2,CustomAttribute3,CustomAttribute4,CustomAttribute5")] RequestsQueueObject requestsqueueobject)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.RequestsQueueObjects.Add(requestsqueueobject);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(requestsqueueobject);
    }
```

Here is the cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PODObject, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PODObject)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PODObject)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: post you get action as well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong but your `PODOObject` doesn't look like a List, an Array or whatever, so you can't really use it as a source for your dropdown...

Comment: Since requestqueueobject should only have one PODObject, I didn't make it a list. But on the view, I want to present list of PODObjects to user so they can choose one.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're looking for is being able to pick from a list of existing `PODObject` instances to set as the related item for `RequestQueueObject`. You've got a few issues you need to clear up for that.

1. You have a property on `RequestQueueObject` to hold the id for the relationship with `PODObject`, but this currently isn't being used. Entity Framework's convention is to look for an property with the naming pattern `[RelatedProperty][RelatedClassIdProperty]`. In your scenario, that would be `PODObjectPODObjectID` or `PODObject_PODObjectID`. You can clear that up by adding the `ForeignKey` attribute to your `PODObjectID` property:

   ```
   [ForeignKey("PODObject")]
   public int PODObjectID { get; set; }
   ```
2. `Html.DropDownListFor` requires an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for its second parameter, which you don't currently have. MVC won't do this for you; you need to create the list of choices yourself. Ideally, you would use a view model with this as a property, but for the time being, you can use `ViewBag`:

   **In your action**

   ```
   var podObjectChoices = db.PODObjects.Select(m => new SelectListItem
       {
           Value = m.PODObjectID,
           Text = m.name
       });
   ViewBag.PODObjectChoices = podObjectChoices.ToList();
   return View();
   ```

   **In your view**

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PODObjectID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PODOBjectChoices, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   ```
3. I pretty much just covered this in the sample code above, but you can't directly set `PODOBject` via a drop down list. Instead, you set the foreign key property for the relationship, `PODOBjectID`, and Entity Framework will wire it up.